# Session time out very short in hosting environment? Test for the loss of sessions?

Tags: c#, session, hosting, session-timeout

My sessions timeouts are very short on my hosting environment, some times even 2 seconds and they timeout.

The sessions are reset if the user continues to use the website, unless the session = null and the count is 0.

The sessions should time out after 20min and then redirect the user to the log in page

The code for this is below:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Session != null && this.Session.Count > 0)
    {
        string email = (string)this.Session["Email"];
        int practiceId = (int)this.Session["PracticeId"];
        int practitionerId = (int)this.Session["PractitionerId"];

        this.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("loggedInUserName", email);
        this.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("practiceId", practiceId.ToString());
        this.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("practitionerId", practitionerId.ToString());
    }
    else
    {    
        this.Session.Abandon();
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");    
    }

    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

Does anyone know why my session timeout could be so short?
When using my site sometime i can move around for 2-5 minutes with no timeout and other time 10s in i get a time out. What could cause session being lost, are they any ways to avoid or test for the loss of sessions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are overriding the init function for the page, but potentially abandoning the session on every page load could cause more issues than it solves.  I would check for the existence of the session inside the master page:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // user is not logged in
        string ReturnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
        string RedirectUrl = "/Login.aspx";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
        {
            RedirectUrl += "?ReturnUrl=" + Server.UrlEncode(ReturnUrl);
        }
        Response.Redirect(RedirectUrl);
    }
}
```

If this is in the master page it will check on each request (made to an aspx page that inherits from the master) that will redirect the user to the login page.

If your app is sharing an application pool, you might be sharing the cookie id with another application:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="60" name="MY_COOOKIE_NAME" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
<sessionState timeout="60" />
```

The MY COOKIE NAME will identify the cookies your app uses, other apps might have the default cookie name, so your sessions although apparently authenticated don't belongto the app as they are getting overwritten by a different app. The sliding expiration means that your session time will be extended everytime you visit a page.

Also, check that the machineKey config element is present, this made my sessions more stable:

```
<machineKey 
validationKey="random_validation_key" 
decryptionKey="random_decryption_key" 
validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```